# How to avoid double imports in typescript – import type and import of actual module

Tags: typescript, eslint, package.json

I have a typescript-based library with the following index.ts

```
export type MyType = {...}

export myObj: MyType = {...}
```

When I build the lib, I have the following files generated:

```
index.js <-- contains only myObj
index.d.ts <-- contains only MyType
```

When I consume the lib, in order to import type, I have to explicitly say that I am importing a type, so I have double imports like this

```
import type {MyType} from 'mylib'
import {myObj} from 'mylib'
```

what I'd like to have instead is

```
import {myObj, MyType} from 'mylib'
```

but if I do this, tsc complains that it cannot find MyType in 'mylib'.

How can I configure compilation / publishing of mylib in order to use single import in consumer projects?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got confused, this wasn't actually a typescript issue. It was an error from eslint, specifically import/named rule

Applying this is supposed to help with it https://github.com/import-js/eslint-import-resolver-typescript